# Parse JSON message manually in C

Tags: c, json, parsing

I need to parse manually, without external libraries, a `JSON` message coming from a server, in `C language`.

The message coming from server would be like:

```
{[CR+LF]
"Tmg": "R",[CR+LF]
"STP": 72[CR+LF]
}[CR+LF]
```

or

```
{[CR+LF]
"Tmg": "R",[CR+LF]
"STP": 150[CR+LF]
}[CR+LF]
```

I need the number after `STP:`. The number is different in each message structure, so I need to get that number from the JSON structure. I can't use external libraries because this code is in an embedded system and exernal code is not allowed.

I tried this following:

```
int main (){
    const char response_message[35] = "{\r\n\"Tmg\":\"R\",\r\n\"STP\":72,\r\n}";
    const char needle[8] = "P\":";
    char *ret;

    ret = strstr(response_message, needle);

    printf("The number is: %s\n", ret);

return 0;
}
```

But obviously, I am getting this result:

```
The number is: P":72,
}
```

So I need to only get the number, how can I get this?

Thanks

Comment: too broad! And stack overflow is not do my work! You could use `strtok()`

Comment: you can use regex in order to define some string patterns and get specific information from this pattern. please explore regex libraries for C language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a hacked solution. Use strstr () to find "STP": then find the following , or } and extract the digits in between.

And that's a hack. Not guaranteed to work. For something that's guaranteed to work, you use a JSON parser.

Comment: The real question is how the message is generated, and what parts of its structure are guaranteed. If it is generated explicitely that way and not by using high level structures and a JSON library (said differently if it only *happens* to look like a JSON message), this is not a hack but a dedicated parser.